# How do I change or update <p> tag data with every client request

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

there is my code,

```
if(data.country_name == 'India'){
        $('.fact').append("<h2 id='india'>Fact about India</h2>");
    $('.fact').append("<p>The world's highest cricket ground is in Chail, Himachal Pradesh. Built in 1893 after leveling a hilltop, this cricket pitch is 2444 meters above sea level.</p>");
$(.fact).append('<p>2</p>')
$(.fact).append('<p>3</p>')
$(.fact).append('<p>4</p>')
    console.log('this a india');
    } else if(data.country_name == 'Turkey'){
        $('.fact').append("<h2 id='turkey'>Fact about Turkey</h2>");
        $('.fact').append('<p>The story of Santa Claus originated in Turkey</p>');
    }else if(data.country_name == 'Russia'){
        $('.fact').append("<h2 id='russia'>Fact about Russia</h2>");
        $('.fact').append('<p>Russia is home to some 20 percent of the world’s trees, and one-fifth of the world’s freshwater is in Lake Baikal.</p>');
    }
```

now, if I add 4 `<p>` for India's fact in the class='fact', so whenever the client location is India, it needs to show 1 random `<p>` from the if statement

anyone can help, I make it complicated, I know it may be too simple!!

Answer (score 0):

Just set up your `facts` as an array and use `Math.random()` with `Math.floor()` to pick a  random one

```
if(data.country_name == 'India'){
    $('.fact').append("<h2 id='india'>Fact about India</h2>");
    let facts = [
       "The world's highest cricket ground is in Chail, Himachal Pradesh. Built in 1893 after leveling a hilltop, this cricket pitch is 2444 meters above sea level.", 
       "fact2",
       "fact3",
       "fact4"];
    $('.fact').append('<p>' + facts[Math.floor(Math.random()*facts.length)] + '</p>')
    console.log('this a india');
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cut down a lot of code repetition by adding some structure to the data in an object or array and look up what you need based on `data.country.name`

Something like:

```
const countries = {
   'India': {
        id: 'india',
        title: 'Facts about India',
        facts: ['I-1','I-2', 'I-3','I-4']
   },
   'Turkey': {
        id: 'turkey',
        title: 'Facts about Turkey',
        facts: ['T-1','T-2', 'T-3','T-4']
   }
}

const item = countries[data.country_name],
      fact = item.facts[Math.floor(Math.random()*item.facts.length)],

      $head = $('<h2>',{id: item.id, text: item.title}),
      $p = $('<p>',{text: fact));

$('.fact').append($head, $p);
```